# How to loop through a string (variables) and recode values?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have a data frame with a large number of variables. A subset of those variables have names with a single number in the name (e.g. `x1_v` and `x2_v`) and I want to recode values of those variables for a subset of arbitrary size. I tried the following using a for-loop but it does not recode anything.

```
library(car)
library(magrittr)

# Sample df
x1_v <- seq(1:5)
x2_v <- rep(5,5)
fun <- c("a","b","c","r","q")
data <- data.frame(x1_v, x2_v, fun)

# Loop
for (i in 1:2){
 paste0("data$x", i, "_v") %>% 
     assign(paste0("data$x", i, "_v") %>%
     recode("c(0, 5) = NA"))
}
```

I know this violates pretty much all R protocol by using looping and `assign()` but I am trying to understand

1. Why this doesn't work
2. How I might use something like apply to address this.

I think making a list makes sense but I want to keep all of my data in the data frame class at the end.

Comment: `library(car)` i'm guessing for referencing `recode()`

Comment: It might be helpful to provide an example of what you'd like the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the bit that doesn't work:

   ```
   assign(paste0("data$x", i, "_v") %>%
       recode("c(0, 5) = NA")
   ```

   You are passing `recode` a string for like "data$x1_v" for `var` when it needs a vector variable. If you want to get into the realm of combining strings to form expressions and function calls you should look at `eval()`, but I think that's way overkill for what you are trying to do. Another reason to avoid that style of programming is it will not play nicely with `%>%`.
2. If I read your code correctly, you are trying to recode columns in your data frame matching a certain pattern in the name. You have asked for a vectorised solution and `dplyr` has facilities that can help with that. `dplyr::mutate_at()` would be good choice. There's a `dplyr::recode()`, but it requires you to specify all your cases exhaustively and is very finicky about types. For example, this is the closest I could come to capturing your intention with `dplyr::recode()`:

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   data %>% 
       mutate_at( .funs = funs(recode(., `0` = NA_real_, 
                                         `5` = NA_real_,
                                         `1` = 1,
                                         `2` = 2,
                                         `3` = 3,
                                         `4` = 4)),
                 .cols = vars(matches("x[0-9].*_v"))
       )
   ```

   Note the use of `.cols = vars(matches("x[0-9].*_v")` which is doing a regex match on column names to find the `x#_v` ones. Also, inside of `funs()` the `.` refers to 'The column I am operating over.' not 'The output passed by pipe.'

   Maybe `ifelse()` or `if_else()` are better options. `ifelse()` (slower and less type safe):

   ```
   data %>% 
       mutate_at( .funs = funs(ifelse(. == 0| . == 5, 
                                      yes = NA,
                                      no = .)),
                  .cols = vars(matches("x[0-9].*_v"))
       )
   ```

   `if_else()` needs the type of `x2_v` and `x1_v` to be the same, which they are not currently. `x2_v <- rep(as.integer(5),5)` would fix this. You could then do:

   ```
   data %>% 
       mutate_at( .funs = funs(if_else(. == 0| . == 5, 
                                       true = NA_integer_,
                                       false = .)),
                  .cols = vars(matches("x[0-9].*_v"))
    )
   ```